# swift asynchronous request using dispatch_group_notify doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I'm trying to use dispatch_group_notify to send a HTTP request where I need to wait for the result of this command before continuing my processing.

here is the following call:

```
self.save(){(response) in
    if let result = response as? Bool {
        if(result == true){
            dispatch_group_notify(self.myGroup!, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                print("send carnet finished")
                let registrationView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("carnetTable") as! CarnetTableViewController
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(registrationView, animated: true)
            })

        }

        }
    }
```

and here is the function who is sending the HTTP command:

```
    func save(callback: (AnyObject) -> ()){
    dispatch_group_enter(self.myGroup)

    let p = pickerDataSource[patients.selectedRowInComponent(0)]

    let params = "owner=\(User.sharedInstance.email)&patient=\(p)&carnet=\(commentaires.text!)"

    let final_url = url_to_request + "?" + params.stringByAddingPercentEncodingForISOLatin1()!
    print("URL addCarnet: \(final_url)")

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: final_url)!

    //let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration,
                               delegate: self,
                               delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
    request.timeoutInterval = 10


    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (
        let data, let response, let error) in
        guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("error data")
            dispatch_group_leave(self.myGroup)
            callback(false)
            return
        }
        var result = NSString(data: data!, encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
        print("result: \(result)")
    }

    task.resume()
    dispatch_group_leave(self.myGroup)
    callback(true)

}
```

I would like to ensure that save function is finished (dispatch_group_leave) before opening the new ViewController (CarnetTableViewController) but I can see that ViewController is called before the end of the dispatch_group...

how can I ensure the end of the save function before opening the new View ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last three lines of your function:

```
task.resume()
dispatch_group_leave(self.myGroup)
callback(true)
```

This causes the task to start, and then you *immediately* (before the task has completed), leave the group and call the `callback`.

If you trace through the code, your `dispatch_group_enter` and `dispatch_group_leave` occur in the same scope, on the same queue, and before you call `callback()`. That means they're not actually doing anything. By the time you get to your callback, the dispatch_group is empty.

If you had an error, I'd expect a problem when that error-leg calls `dispatch_group_leave` a second time (since this is unbalanced).

You meant this:

```
    ...
    var result = NSString(data: data!, encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
    print("result: \(result)")
    dispatch_group_leave(self.myGroup)
    callback(true)
}

task.resume()
```